# replace \n \r and br tags with space in R

Tags: gsub

I want to take off any sort of line breaks from my data since I have to map this data to column in CSV.

I tried:

```
  gsub("[\r\n]", " ...REPLACED........", col)
```

But how to take off br tags as well.

It could be `<br>`, `</br>` or `<br/>`

adding it to

```
[\r\n<br>]
```

does not work.

- I am using gsub in R.

Comment: The first parameter is a regular expression. Try this: `/(\\n)|(\\r)|(<br>)|(<\/br>)/g`

Comment: No, got this: Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/(\\n)|(\\r)|(<br>)|(<\/"